# How can I install Chromium browser on a bootable USB?

Tags: chromium, browser

I am having a hard time installing the Chromium Browser. Do I have to have Ubuntu fully installed to the hard drive to be able to do this?  For the time being, I am booting from USB.

Comment: to get the most useful answer, it s best to include the steps you took to attempt the install and any errors that you got when you did.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes you can install apps to the bootable usb.

Long answer: Installing applications require enough space for the programs to run, so if you have Ubuntu on a small bootable usb then it may not have enough space to install. Also any apps that you install to the bootable drive will be deleted as soon as you shutdown or reboot the computer. You may also need to download new updates even with a fresh install of ubuntu with "sudo apt-get upgrade"

*The bootable live or "try" ubuntu is NOT ment for daily use*

Comment: Mostly true, if you have selected space for "persistence" (a small space is default when installing to USB, I believe) then any chnges you make will remain during reboots.  However, they will not remain during a full install- the installer will just install Ubuntu as normal and all changes will only remain on the USB.

Comment: also the amount of space on the USB is not relevant for the program to *run* the entire Ubuntu OS will be running in the RAM and the USB acts like a HD.  You will of course need enough space to *install* the program.  The USB is meant mostly to *try* but it can be used for repair of another computer or to keep a bootable OS on you that you can boot on any computer(say while travelling).  You will, of course not get the performance  of a full install but functionally it will be nearly the same.  I have used a bootable USB to get the viruses form a Windows system that would not boot.